# Play Framework 2.5 - Redirect encoding issue

Tags: redirect, encoding, utf-8, playframework, playframework-2.5

In my application using Play 2.5, I have to redirect to another url.

It works well when url does not contain any special character

```
Redirect("http://www.withoutaccent.com/ok", 302)
```

It works well when url contains accent encoded in UTF-8

```
Redirect("http://www.withencodedaccent.com/%C3%A9", 302)
```

The issue is when url contains accent

```
Redirect("http://www.withaccent.com/é", 302)
```

Url provided by this code is "http ://www.withaccent.com/**%E9**" which is not correct!
All my application is using **UTF-8** so I don't understand why it uses **Windows-1252** encoding (cf.https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)?

Thanks for your awnsers!